# Getting Error in Unit Testing TeamsFx app

Tags: microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

Is there any recommended framework to be used for unit testing the application built using TeamsFx tab app that can be integrated in a CI/CD pipeline.

I've tried using Jest and Enzyme but was getting errors. Are there any sample projects that can be referred for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question, in our practice we use Jest or Mocha for unit testing framework. Since it is a standard Node project, you can follow the industry best practice to setup unit test by Jest/Mocha.